# IBM Worklight on Xamarin Studio Server Start issue

Tags: xamarin, ibm-mobilefirst

After I installed Worklight CLI on my Mac and added the Xamarin Studio Add-In, when I try to click on Start server from the IBM WorkLight menu, I get an error saying "IBM Worklight CLI or JDK not found! Please check IBM Worklight SDK settings preferences/options". Can you help on how to fix this error?

Comment: I have tried logging off, reinstalled CLI, JDK 7 again, but no help. Can someone at least tell me where is the settings/preferences / options menu in IBM worklight SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to make the WorkLight server work. The actual issue I had was with the path for JDK not being set properly in Xamarin Studio. I set the JDK path to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk.jdk/Contents/Home in Xamarin Studio -> Preferences -> IBM Worklight -> SDK Locations

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is tracked internally. This is also mentioned in the known issues in the Getting started.. and we are working on a resolution. you can try the following on a command prompt:

1. Navigate to the Xamarin solution folder and then go to the "worklight" folder under it
2. type "wl start"

   This will start the server
3. type "wl status"

   This should tell you if the worklight server is running.

then go to the console using the menu option and you should be able to login to the console

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, inside my Xamarin Android project, all I see is a Components folder that is related to Worklight and nothing else. Once I go inside it and type **wl start**, I get a message saying, **You must be in a Worklight project to execute this command**.

Comment: Alright, so i have gone past this hurdle and now i have created a worklight project and also deployed it to the server. The server is also up and running. My Xamarin Android application has 2 projects, one is a Android project and another PCL project, where all the real action take place. I have used MVVM architecture so that i can support other platforms easily. **Now the problem is, I don't really see a way to add reference to IBM worklight components to the PCL project and I am stuck. What's the direction now?**

Comment: @ImayaKumar can you please start a new question for the PCL issue? Also please mark this question as closed if the answer helped.

Comment: Sure will do. Let me type in what I did to make the WorkLight server work. The actual issue I had was with the path for JDK not being set properly in Xamarin Studio. I set the JDK path to **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk/Contents/Home** in Xamarin Studio -> Preferences -> IBM Worklight -> SDK Locations

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't want me asking questions anymore. I have to wait for 2 more days to ask a new question.

Comment: Ajay, I went ahead and added reference to the Worklight.Android.dll directly in the PCL project, and now I can reference the classes inside it. However, when I look at the sample application that comes along with the SDK, it uses plain Android project and creates an instance of **WorkLightClient** class by passing the **Android Activity**. In my case, I don't really have an activity explicitly because I am using MVVM (MVVMCross framework) and all my code is in a ViewModel file in the PCL project. I am confused as to how to proceed further on this. Can you help?